# Assign Date to a variable and use it in UiPath

Tags: rpa, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

I need to extract the data of employees from an Excel sheet. The Excel sheet contains the DoB and I need to assign salary according to the DoB. The person born before 1995 will be credited a salary of 50000 and person born after 1995 will be credited a salary of 20000.

I had tried and there was an issue with the date.

[image: UiPath Studio]

Comment: Please go to the UiPath Academy. Your question is very basic and easy to be done. What did you try so far?

Comment: I had done the excel formula, copied that to the write cell and the problem worked. But I need to try another method. I Need to done this fully within the UiPath. I compared the date in each row item and got the DoB that born before 1995. But I don't get  the logic like How to assign the salary.

Comment: Upload some image about the Excel file and about the current state of your Workflow.

Comment: sir I am a new user so i cannot add image into this.I need to earn some points.

Comment: Sheet 1 Id Name Dob                             sheet 2 Id Salary

Comment: Hi, I use the if condition and got the output through writeline like 20000,50000,20000,50000...But how can I write this to the salary column.Can you help?..I need to know where I can store this values and write to the Salary column

Comment: You can upload images somewhere else (like imgur) and link to them. Link is enough. It's very abstract. I'm not sure if anyone guessing what you really want.

Comment: can you see the image? I need to store the output to a salary column. How that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering like the one you need could be done using LINQ but if you are new to VB.NET this may be a little bit too complex approach.
I would suggest using For Each Row cycle to go throuh each DataTable row and use [VB.NET DateTime.CompareTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto) method for comparing two dates (DOB from Excel and 1/1/1996).
You already have the IF statement in your workflow, just use Assign activity to set the salary column, like this:
Left part of the Assign: `row("salary")`
Right part of the Assign: `50000` (or 20000)
Then you could save your calculation back to Excel by using `Write Range` activity